# Excel Pivot R1C1 - Memory Overload

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I am creating a Pivot through VBA using the following code:

```
Dim Pivot30D As Worksheet
Set Pivot30D = Sheets.Add
Pivot30D.Name = "Pivot30D"

Dim Kelekt As Range
Set Kelekt = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
Dim KelektAddress As String
KelektAddress = Kelekt.Parent.Name & "!" & Kelekt.Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    KelektAddress, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot30D!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Here, Kelekt is the range with which I am creating the Pivot. This would work fine in theory except I get a quick memory overload. Insufficient memory. On the other hand, I can create this pivot just fine if I use "R2C1:R191995C24" (with the quotation marks) instead of Kelekt. All I need (hopefully) to make this work is to convert Kelekt into RC notation and pass it that way.

How do I do that? Failing that, how do I make this code work otherwise?

Edit: The latest error is PivotTable Field Name Is Not Valid

Comment: try step through your code and check what is the address of `Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))` ? It may have selected the entire columns or entire rows hence causing the memory overload.

Comment: It isn't, but it is a huge range nonetheless. Kazimierz's answer is pretty close to what I need, but for some reason it yields an empty Pivot.

Comment: do your source table has values in each and every cells (escpecially the last row and the last column)? if not, try adjust End() sequence provided by @karzimimierz or find other ways to select the entire source table.

Comment: It does, I was very meticulous about that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested changes:

```
Dim Kelekt As Range
Set Kelekt = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

dim KelektAddress as String
    KelektAddress = Kelekt.Parent.Name & "!" & Kelekt.address(true, true, xlR1C1)
```

And use `KelektAddress` instead of `Kelekt` in `SourceData:=` parameter.

Comment: This creates the pivot empty without any values.

Comment: you are possibly missing reference to right sheet. Are you sure that data sheet is active when you trigger your macro? see also changes with `.Kelekt.Parent.Name` in my answer

Comment: Perhaps the bigger picture would help find the issue. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Look, after you added new sheet it is empty (if your code is completed). Then `Kelekt range` refers to almost whole sheet except first row. But still it is empty range. You should go back to 'data sheet' before setting `Kelekt` references.

Comment: Kudos sir, you are quite the expert! I added "Worksheets("Source").Activate" before the Kelekt references and it's all set. 

Your invaluable assistance is very appreciated. :)